# Finite Difference Function Index Error:

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, physics

Below is a function for the finite difference method, it's a very standard way of calculating the derivative given some function f(x), a mesh (np.linspace), as well as a uniform distance between the each piece of the grid (h).

The problem being encountered is when I try a known function, (say x**2) across a mesh from 0,10; I am receiving a specific error. After the code I will post the error that's encountered.

```
def finitedifference(f,x,h,n):
"""f : function you are attempting to differentiate.
   x : grid/domain with with you will differentiate.
   h : distance between uniform mesh.
   n : required for loop?"""
    df = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i in range(1,n):
        df[i] = (f[i+1]-f[i-1])/(2*h)
        #end_points
        df[0] = (f[1]-f[0])/h
        df[-1] = (f[-1]-f[-2])/h
    return print(df)
```

What I use:

```
f = x**3
x = np.linspace(0,10,11)
h = x[1] - x[0]
finitedifference(f,x,h,11)
```

I receive the error:

```
"IndexError: index 11 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 11"
```

Unfortunately I am not sure what this means, so maybe some clarification on the error/remedies for it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An array (or list) of size 11 has indices `0, 1, 2, ..., 10`.

If you do a `for` loop over `range(1, 11)`, it iterates over `1, 2, 3, ..., 10`. If you then try to access index `i+1`, you'll end up outside of your array when `i` reaches `10`.

On the other hand, you have left out index `0`. Therefore, you probably want to use `for i in range(n-1)` to ensure that you'll start from the top and stay within limits.